# ViteJS: dependency prebundling issue with 3rd party library? works fine for build but not for dev

Tags: vite, es6-modules

I am using a third party library that uses momentjs internally in its library. Looking at the source code of the library it uses the `import * as moment from 'moment'` import statement. And it calls a function in its code using `moment.isMoment(...)` which crashes my app at runtime stating `TypeError: (void 0) is not a function`. This error happens at development mode but not after build. How should I configure it so that it works both on development and production?